# Picking Country,state and city from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

on my website, I want to implement functionality like picking a country name from the dropdown and according to the country I want to show a dropdown of state and city

is there any jquery highly customizable library to implement this functionality?

Comment: you can use [this blog](https://codingshiksha.com/javascript/node-js-project-to-get-all-countriesstates-cities-list-in-world-in-command-line-using-country-state-city-library-full-project-for-beginners/) to get all `countries -> cities -> states`  as a `JSON` file ( use `npm i country-state-city`) . and then you can simply use `Select2` as a jQuery highly customizable library.